# If $G$ is a non-empty set, with all its elements being regular, then all of its elements has an inverse element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, monoid

> Suppose you have $G$ a non-empty, finite set, with a $* $ law, and having the identity element $1_G$. Suppose also that all of $G$ elements are regular, that is: for a $a \in G$, $\forall b,c \in G $: $$a *b = a * c \implies b=c $$ and $$ b * a = c * a \implies b = c $$
>   Show that all elements of $G$ have an inverse on the left and on the right.

I've struggling to do anything with this exercise. I think I have to show that if $a *b =  a*c$ implies that $b$ is the inverse element, but not sure how to proceed. I guess that $a * b \in G$, and that the operation of $*$ of $a$ by $b$ gives a unique result, that is there is no couple $c,d \in G$ such that $c \not = a$ and $c*d = a*b$.

Comment: Don't forget that $G$ is assumed to be *finite*. Consider $(\mathbb{N},+)$ to see that this hypothesis is necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $a\in G$ the map $b\mapsto a*b$ is injective.

Then - since $G$ is finite - it must also be surjective, so $a*b=1_G$ for some $b$, proving that $a$ has a right inverse..

Likewise for the other side.